# Displaying popup when data processing is going on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a html file [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UGHXv/). The table can contain more than 2000 rows. On clicking on each row, some related data will be displayed in separate pane.

```
    $('table tr').on('click', function () {
        $('#showContent').html($(this).find('.content').html());
    });
```

I want to add a popup to display processing message, which will be displayed on clicking on any row before displaying row related data in separate pane. Once the data is ready to display, then popup should be closed automatically. Any thoughts!

Comment: Binding events to 2000 rows is computationally expensive. Better to delegate the event - `$('table').on('click', 'tr', ...`

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery [blockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin:

```
$('table tr').on('click', function () {
        $('#showContent').html($(this).find('.content').html());

        $.ajax({
            url: url
            ...
            beforeSend: function(){$.blockUI();}
            complete: function(){$.unblockUI();}
        });
    });
```